# Select distinct data from one to many relation tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models

**`model A`** (id, name, status) and 
**`model B`** (id, A.id, created),
Every time I change status of A and create a new row in B.

I want to join A and B for getting the latest created for each A.

I tried this but I am not getting distinct

```
select a.id, a.status, max(aas.created) 
from a  
inner join b on a.id=b.a.id 
group by a.created, a.id, b.a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to acheive this. It will be a little change in your query it gives the latest created:

```
select a.id, a.user_id,a.job_id, aas.created from public.application a  inner join public.application_status aas on aas.application_id=a.id where aas.created = 
(select max(aas.created) from public.application_status aas)
```

if you want it for each A

```
select a.id, a.user_id,a.job_id, aas.created 
from public.application a  
inner join (select aas.application_id, max(aas.created) from 
public.application_status aas group by aas.application_id) as on as.application_id=a.id
```

Comment: this will return only one row with max created

Comment: Ok, isee, the first query gives the last of all A, and the second one the last for each A.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use aggregation?

```
select a.id, a.status, max(b.created) 
from a  inner join
     b
     on a.id = b.a.id 
group by a.id, a.status;
```